# Blocks and CSS Grid Systems

Tags: theming, blocks

How do I achieve the following in Drupal:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">[MY BLOCK HERE]</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">[MY BLOCK HERE]</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">[MY BLOCK HERE]</div>
</div>
```

I can use the "Block Class" module to assign the grid system classes to the block, however this does not allow me reuse blocks in another layout (changing the grid system classes).

Im also limited to where I can put these blocks. At the moment i have a specific region setup that is wrapped in the "row" class. This prevents me for having a few different rows and from placing the blocks anywhere...

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">[MY BLOCK HERE]</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">[MY BLOCK HERE]</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">[MY BLOCK HERE]</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">[MY BLOCK HERE]</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">[MY BLOCK HERE]</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">[MY BLOCK HERE]</div>
</div>
```

Basically I need to:

1. Add grid system classes to blocks
2. Reuse blocks in a different grid system class configuration
3. Freedom to define rows of blocks and assign them to any region, not just one that is wrapped in a single "row" class.

Any help would be much appreciated, at the moment I have to style each individual block to work responsively and I know that there must be a better way of doing this.

Thanks

Comment: Why aren't you using a theme with built in grid like Omega?

Comment: If I correctly understood - you want a responsive theme. Omega has these capabilities out of the box, for example; it also helps building the layout, change grid between break points (using media queries) and more. Did I misunderstood you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We primarily build our sites using Bootstrap with this same technique, so here are 3 modules that will make your life a lot easier.

[Block Class](https://drupal.org/project/block_class) - add classes to blocks.

[Block Group](https://drupal.org/project/blockgroup) and/or [Region Class](https://drupal.org/project/regionclass) - group blocks together in faux regions, add classes to regions.

[Blocker](https://drupal.org/project/blocker) - places blocks on specific pages in different regions, alternative to using the core block placement system. Really useful for site building and putting blocks on basic pages.

[image: Blocker Interface]

Comment: Yes, but more eloquently and without you pulling your hair out. I attached a screenshot above, but you can see that on any node, all the regions show up and you can place a block anywhere, with added classes. Under "Secondary", you can see there's a menu block placed by the block system, so it's considered global.