# Layouts using the grid system

Tags: 8, bootstrap-theme

How can I lay out blocks or paragraphs using Bootstrap's grid system? I found [this seven-year-old answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/85557/99084) and am hoping things have evolved since then, and if so would like to know how.

My best stab at cobbling together something at this point is to use Paragraphs for the content and use the Block Class module to assign the desired Bootstrap class to each paragraph type. Is there a more obvious and cleaner solution to the problem in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Paragraphs Grid](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs_grid) module provides this functionality.

> With Paragraphs Grid, you can display multiple paragraph entities in a
>   grid. **Supports Out-Of-The-Box Bootstrap 3.0 and 4.0** and CSS grid
>   from MDC (Material Design).

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

paragraphs are generated under the block system if you create under content type, and for the bootstrap to happens you have to add in your css skills into it and as for ready solutions, you can use https://www.drupal.org/project/ds and https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_layouts

this should be your good starting point :)